# Wrong RecordCount on Filtered Form with SQL View DataSource

Tags: ms-access, vba, record-count

I am using an **Access2010 project** as frontend, referring to a **MS SQL Server 2008** as backend. Within my Access project there is form `frmKlientenÜbersicht`. This form has a view `abfKlientenÜbersicht` as dataSource.

Now I am trying to get the current number of records showing up in my form by using this code:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
    Debug.Print "Form_Current: " & anzahlDatensätze
    lblAnzahlDatensätze.Caption = anzahlDatensätze & " Klient(en)"
End Sub

Private Function anzahlDatensätze() As Integer
    Dim rs As Recordset
    Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone
    rs.MoveLast
    anzahlDatensätze = rs.RecordCount
End Function
```

This works fine until I am using some filters. If I am **using any filter** on my form, the **number of records stays unchanged**!

- What do I have to change to get the current number of records showing up (if filtered or not)?
- What is the reason why my code does not show the correct number of records?

[image: Access Project Overview]

EDIT: According to the given comments and answers I tried setting `Count([pkKlient]` onto a textbox (see new pic) and tried `DCount("*", "abfKlientenÜbersicht", me.Filter)` from within VBA Code.

Unfortunatelly it seems that the **filterClause is not valid** when using it as parameter value for DCount. (see pic for filterClause).

As you can see `count(..)` does not result in a correct number - and the filterClause (*generated by access!!*) seems not to be valid for use by `DCount(..)`

If someone wants to try it, on your own, just create an ADP, add a form, add a view, form dataSource is a view, set a filter, and try to get the number of records?!!

Looking forward for **any comments/answers/hints!**

[image: form Screenshot when filtered]

Comment: Can you also show us your filters?

Comment: Filters will be *set dynamically by the user*, by clicking on the according access RibbonBarButtons and choosing values to filter for!

Comment: Apology for not being explicitly clear. Best guess here that you are looking at a `paramterized query`. So why not look at the SQL View after adding the filters :)

Comment: Unfortunatelly I am not quite sure what you meant - perhaps you can add an anser showing/describing how to implement your solution. Furthermore all I want to know is the number of records - which access is already showing in the navigation bar at the bottom (eg: 1 of 4 - filtered). IMO the requested information is already somewhere *within* access - I just do not know how to get it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some notes, there are a dozen things that could go wrong with this, it could hardly even be called tested. However, it was returning the correct count for me.

Apparently, the form filter just hides records, whereas this will apply a real filter. However, you need to get the format into the right shape for a valid filter. In the end, a WHERE statement would probably be easier.

```
Private Sub Form_ApplyFilter(Cancel As Integer, ApplyType As Integer)

    With Me.Recordset
        ''Filter
        If ApplyType = 1 Then
            ''Very, very roughly. Remove form name, use single quotes
            ''You will need a lot more code for safety
            sfilter = Replace(Me.Filter, "[" & Me.Name & "].", "")
            sfilter = Replace(sfilter, """", "'")

            .Filter = sfilter 

            MsgBox "Recordset : " & Me.Recordset.RecordCount & vbCrLf _
            & "Filtered : " & .RecordCount

        Else
            ''Remove filter - ApplyType 0
            .Filter = ""
        End If

    End With

End Sub
```

**Additional note with similar caveats**

You can also set a textbox to something on these lines:

```
=IIf([FilterOn]=True,DCount("id","ATable",
 Replace(Replace([Filter],"[" & [Name] & "].",""),"""","'")),Count([id]))
```

(Remove the break in the line, it is cosmetic)

Comment: thx for your input - at least this may be an explanation why `count` did not return the right number for me. When you stated, that you did get a correct result, _where you using an SQL Server as backend and Access as frontend_? When using an Access **database** I do get the correct results too

Comment: I just wonder what kind of logic/function Access is using - as it shows the correct number right away?! (see second screenshot in question)

Comment: I used Access 2010 and SQL Server Express 2012 to create an adp. Initially I got the same results as you outline, that is, a form of seemingly filtered data and a count that did not match. I put the above together from a number of posts on the issue. It depends on applying a filter to the recordset, not the form.

Comment: Note that this is a problem with adps and does not exist at all for linked tables, which is now the recommended way of using a back-end database.

Comment: I am using linked tables, and a query as dataSource for the form. Unfortunatelly I am still having the problem. Assigning a filter to the recordset may be a solution, but takes the user the possibility to make use of the built-in filter feature... Found a solution which divided the height of the form by the height of a record to get the correct number

Comment: When I say linked tables, I mean in a normal accdb, not adp.

Comment: Although your answer helped me - I am still a bit irritated how access does this kind of magic (counting visible records with clientFilter and query as dataSource)?? *thx for your input!*

Answer (score 1):

with VBA, `DCount` will give you what you need

```
DCount("*", "MyTable", Me.Filter)
```

If you want to put this on the form, there's an easier way. use an unbound box, and set it to `=count([FieldName])`

[image: using Count in form proerties]

This count should remain correct, regardless of if it's counted filtered records or not.

Comment: unfortunatelly `Count([primaryKeyColumn])` does not result in a correct number of records, and `DCount` from within my VBA code does not work. Seems that *FilterClause* (generated by access) is not valid - see edited question..